# error loading image shape with no dimension

Tags: python, arrays, image, deep-learning, shapes

I am quite new with Deep Learning.
I used this code to transform few images into tensors for a CNN with shape `(#images, height,width, channels)`.
I downloaded the images one by one from a remote server to my pc. The code works for them and returns Image shape of `(30,96,96,3).`
But when I run it with a bigger dataset (like 100, 300 images or even bigger), downloaded as .zip and then unzipped, the code reports Image shape of `(100,)` without dimensions.
I thought there was a problem with my pc but I tried to run the code even on a remote server with bigger computational power and the story was the same.
Can it be possible that the **"zip process"** modified the Image characteristics in some way?

```
def load_images_and_labels(categories):
img_lst = []
labels = []
for index, category in enumerate(categories):
    for image_name in os.listdir(fpath + "/" + category):
        img = cv2.imread(fpath + "/" + category + "/" + image_name)
        img_array = Image.fromarray(img, 'RGB')
        img_lst.append(np.array(img_array))
        labels.append(index)

return img_lst, labels


images, labels = load_images_and_labels(categories)

images = np.array(images)
labels = np.array(labels)

print("Images shape = ", images.shape, "\nLabels shape = ", labels.shape)
```

Comment: Try running `img = cv2.imread(filepath)` for one of those images that does not work well and check img.shape

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured it out what the problem was. In my dataset there are some images with different size and this is why the shape for all the images doesn't show up. I resized all the images and even tried to delete images with a different shape and in both cases the code worked well.